# Best way to migrate dependancies from virtualenv to to another virtualenv

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have a django project in a virtualenv, I'm trying to move to a new machine.

On the new machine, can I just create a new virtualenv and copy/paste the lib folder from the old machine into the new one (inside the new virtualenv)?

Or do I need to actually run the installation for each of the libraries?  The reason I'm asking is because I have modified several of the libraries I am using.  If I reinstalled all my dependancies on a new machine, first of all that would be really time consuming, and second, it wouldn't even run.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to do this.  My main concern is the lib folder..

Comment: Are those modified versions hosted anywhere? It would be easier to test and deploy if they were accessible on e.g. GitHub rather than copy-pasting the whole project folder.

Comment: they are not hosted anywhere

Comment: Then that is going to make your life a bit more difficult; each modified library *will* need to be separately installed and manually kept up-to-date. As it stands, this question seems too broad.

Comment: Then I suppose I will move all my modified dependancies to github, and figure out how to do it from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure all the versions are the same (which you probably do), then in the original virtualenv (activated), issue:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Then port that file to the new one, and

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

This will always hardcode version numbers so be sure, if this applies to you, to update all your dependencies first.

Comment: Note that this won't handle locally-modified dependencies, unless they're also hosted somewhere and installed appropriately.

Comment: they are not hosted anywhere

Comment: Sorry I missed the local modifications part. I agree that you should really be using git for this and that whatever you are concerned with that you are modifying should just be under your source control, not the purview of the generic virtualenv scripts.